# How to group the rows from a multidimensional array of numbers?

Tags: java

I've been trying to sort this multidimensional array **without using** array.sort

```
int arg[][] = {
        {26, 39, 3, 13},
        {22, 97, 17, 123},
        {46, 19, 63, 123},
        {1, 37, 90, 32},
        {17, 37, 90, 32}};
```

Into this

```
int arg[][] = {
        {3, 13, 26, 39}, 
        {17,22,97,123}, 
        {19, 46, 63, 123},
        {1, 32, 37, 90},
        {17, 32, 37, 90}};
```

It sorts the rows from the lowest number to the highest.

Using a bubble sort, I have tweaked this code and done everything but it only sorts the first 3 rows and it and throws an out of bound error.

This is the code I have

```
for (int i = arg[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i ; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < i ; k++) {
                if (arg[k][j] > arg[k][j + 1]) {
                    int temp = arg[k][j];
                    arg[k][j] = arg[k][j + 1];
                    arg[k][j + 1] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arg[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arg[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It throws this "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at ejemplo.Ejemplo.main(Ejemplo.java:43)
Java Result: 1" when I remove the -1 in the first line.

Comment: When I don't remove the -1 , it kind of works but only with the first 3 rows.

Comment: @geil Please edit your question to add your notes about the Exception message and how it's affected by the insertion or removal of `-1`. That will make your question more complete and easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said last 2 rows are not sorted.I print out your indexces that you are iterating over which showed me that you dint reach to last 2 rows .Instead you can do

```
for (int i = arg[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arg.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < arg[j].length - 1; k++) {

            if (arg[j][k] > arg[j][k + 1]) {
                int temp = arg[j][k];
                arg[j][k] = arg[j][k + 1];
                arg[j][k + 1] = temp;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/vIDRO2)

Comment: And how would it be with the column 0 sorted out from the lowest to the highest, apart from sorting all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Why is i used a the stopping condition on the sort loops. Couldn't it be something like arg [i].length, as follows.

```
for (int i = arg[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arg [i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < arg [i].length ; k++) {
            if (arg[i][j] > arg[i][k]) {
                int temp = arg[i][j];
                arg[i][j] = arg[i][k];
                arg[i][k] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arg[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arg[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Otherwise on the 5th element i = 4 but there are only 4 elements in each inner array so the maximum valid index is 3

Answer (score 0):

Classic Implementation of Bubble Sort

```
private static void bubblesort(Integer[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1]) > 0) {
                swap(j, j+1, array);
            }
        }
    }

}

private static void swap(Integer index1, Integer index2, Integer[] array) {
    if(index1 == index2)return;
    Integer temp = new Integer(array[index2]);
    array[index2] = array[index1];
    array[index1] = temp;

}
```